# How to calculate area of a plot of land from a photo (with acceptable error rate)?

Tags: area

[image: Picture of the plot of land]

I want to calculate the area enclosed by the yellow lines. It also needs to account for the missing piece of land out of the picture by extending the yellow lines. Since no scale is given, I guess we have to assume some scale (error rate up to few square meters is acceptable) from the known objects in the image like the car. Is it possible to calculate the area with atleast some reasonable accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

I considered 5m the van, too. I looked on a site for a van almost identical to the picture.

Then I used pixels and without considering the perspective, which is negligible, I got $86\text{m}\times 135\text{m}=11610$m$^2$

Answer (score 0):

Just below the square is a yellow building with a white van parked outside.  By counting the windows, you can find out what sort of van that is and how long it is.   The van is parallel to the top left side of the rectangle.  So now you can measure that side.  Then you can use that side to measure the other side.

Comment: Assuming the length of the car to be 5 meters and i can stack 20 such cars along its width, giving me x=100m and length (y) seems to be roughly twice the width (y=200m), the area comes to 20000 square meters or ~5 acres. Can someone with practical knowledge of lands confirm this to be roughly around 5 acres?

Comment: I know that a typical city block in a residential area is roughly 2.5 acres.  But this can vary wildly.